# How to check the response Status of Anchor tag decorated with data=ajax=true

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Please excuse my error title as i couldn't find a better one. I have a anchor tag as following. This calls my MVC Action to bring and display Json data into Specified Div.

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#MyDiv" href="/Home/GetData">Click Me</a>
```

Now my problem is , I want to intercept the response status for error handling purposes. How can I check json response in this scenario? The thing we do in normal Jquery Ajax call e.g. Success , Error etc

Comment: Where are the docs for whatever library you are using that reads these attributes and makes the ajax calls? They aren't done by jQuery library alone

Comment: This link gets generated by pagedList,mvc

Comment: That is meaningless to anyone that doesn't use MVC or .Net or whatever back end framework you are using. There is some javascript library being used also

Comment: Yes, that's why Original question doesn't have that. I want to somehow intercept post click, if that exist.

Comment: but the docs for the library probably have that information or some of it. Also jQuery has global ajax event handlers you could use http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: It doesn't have that.

Comment: Provide link to library docs. Based on what you are asking if you don't have that control....why use it and not write your own? Anyway...global event handlers are probably what you want

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/qayuhe/1/edit?js,output

You can just using the HTML attribute,then just using the `XMLHttpRequest` function